# Showing entire line of vim

Tags: vim, command-line, vi, macvim

Say I paste the entire jquery function into a file (just as an example.. i know thats not practical but for sake of example).

WHen you try to scroll past it, it shows 1 line of it and then 'jumps' to the code under it. I want it to behave just like normal.. if wordwrap is on then when i scroll it just scrolls through the one large long line normally, not try to jump before it and after it and then fill it in with tons of whitespace

Comment: As a bit of a non-answer, why are you wrapping lines when writing code? You should be keeping lines to 80 characters or fewer.

Comment: btw -- you could just zap it with ``vipgq`` and it'll add linebreaks to the text for you

Comment: No need to invoke visual mode -`gqip` is faster. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive I understand your question, but if you want to be able to use the normal directional keys (<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>) to navigate up and down wrapped lines instead of entire lines of code, you can remap the keys as such:

```
map j gj
map k gk
```

For a more in-depth solution to your problem (including additional mapping, and a leader function to change mappings with wrap mode), see ["Move cursor by display lines when wrapping"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping).

Comment: paste all of this into vim: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js  , then try to scroll down past the huge chunk of text (make sure you have :set wrap on). add some code beneath it, just random text and try scrolling up and down.. it will show ALL or NONE of the jquery, it wont scroll normally showing the bottom of the jquery by one line...  scroll more shows 2 lines, etc

Comment: it all jumps at once by like 300 lines, and when you scroll down to see the code it jumps away from the jquery line

Comment: All right, I think I understand. You don't like that some window space is left empty when wrapping a line too large to fit in the window?

Comment: yes correct, that too.. and also i dont like how it 'jumps'. its like it shows all of it or none of it. If you scroll up to the very top it leaves all the rest blank, i dont like that either. I want it to act like as if you just pasted it in notepad. When you scroll it just... scrolls through it, no gimmicks

Comment: From what I've read since I've started to use Vim the same question has been asked a lot of times before and IIRC the answer is always negative.